# PHP is not loading

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I install my webserver as Debian 10 with Nginx and installed the PHP7.3 with MariaDB.
The info.php is not loading on the browser and the browser shows a blank screen. I've checked error log and there is below lines there:
The Error is:

```
    - 2020/08/14 05:28:31 [info] 2782#2782: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
    - 2020/08/14 05:45:38 [info] 14940#14940: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
    - 2020/08/14 05:45:51 [info] 14949#14949: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
    - 2020/08/14 06:01:27 [info] 15179#15179: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
    - 2020/08/14 06:01:35 [info] 15188#15188: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
    - 2020/08/14 06:11:10 [info] 15370#15370: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
```

========================================================================

can someone please help me to resolve the issue? Here is the default configuration for server block too:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/rs/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your error.log shows only info messages so far. What return message does your browser get? (You can check this in the network tab of the developer tools, usually F12 key opens these.

Comment: No error, Is not showing anything. it shows:
<!--?
 phpinfo();
 phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?-->

Comment: I think this post would be a better fit at unix.stackexchange.com